# CSS exponential number

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

My javascript code works with doubles, and when I convert an array to string, I get this result: `transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1.2246468525851679e-16, 0, 0, -1.2246468525851679e-16, -1, 0, 0, -1.224646841997256e-14, -100, 1);`

This doesn't works in css, because `1.224646841997256e-14` is invalid in CSS.

```
var toStr = function (a) {
    return  'matrix3d(' + a[0] + ', ' + a[1] + ', ' + a[2] + ', ' + a[3] + ', ' +
            a[4] + ', ' + a[5] + ', ' + a[6] + ', ' + a[7] + ', ' +
            a[8] + ', ' + a[9] + ', ' + a[10] + ', ' + a[11] + ', ' + 
            a[12] + ', ' + a[13] + ', ' + a[14] + ', ' + a[15] + ')';
};
```

How should I fix it?
Number.toFixed works, but I have to give a digit number, and the string is very large. For example `(1.0).toFixed(16)==1.0000000000000000`

Comment: Why is it important that the numbers have perfect precision in a `toString` function?

Comment: because the 3d transforms require good precision. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is pre-process your `a` array to generate valid CSS value numbers (without exponential notation).

The limitation is due to the CSS specification for the arguments used in the `matrix3d`
functions, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number

You are on the right track with the `.toFixed()` function, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

In your case, fix the numbers to 0 length if you want simple integers or a few decimal places depending on the application.

Note that the numbers like `1.2246468525851679e-16` are essentially `0.0` for all practical purposes.  You don't need 16 decimal places of precision.

I think the syntax may be as simple as (for 4 decimal places):

```
(a[6]).toFixed(4);
```

but try it out first.

Comment: (1.5).toFixed() returns 2. If there is no arguments, then the number is rounded, and there is no fractional part.

Comment: Good point, add a few decimal places, for example, `.toFixed(4)` should be precise enough.